# How do I write golang zerologs to Redis?

Tags: go, logging, zerolog

I need to send zerolog logs to redis for a project and there seems to be an error in the way I am doing it.

I realize that in order to send a new output to zerolog, I need to send an io.Writer Type.  So, I created a struct that has a specific io.Writer as shown below.

```
type RedisWriter struct {
    client *redis.ClusterClient
}
var redisWriter = RedisWriter{client: pub}

func (w RedisWriter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    redisChannel := "COPS_LOGS"
    fmt.Println("blah")

    err = pub.Publish(ctx, redisChannel, p).Err()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error publishing message")
        return 0, err
    }
    return len(p), nil
}

func init() {
    
    logger = zerolog.New(redisWriter).With().Timestamp().Logger()
}
```

When I run the logger, I see the new Write method I created is never even being touched.  When debugging through the code in zerolog, I see that the code is hitting the Write method in Zerolog.  Do you know what I am doing wrong and what the fix is?

I also tried adding the redisWriter as a SyncWriter and as a MultiLevelWriter with the ConsoleWriter, but had no success.

Comment: Have you used the `logger` created here? If the issue is that the `Write` method is not called, it has nothing to do with redis. Try to reduce your demo to narrow down the issue. I just created a simple demo (https://go.dev/play/p/nqHJoMY38hC) and it works as expected. Try to modify this demo to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Thank you!  This was really helpful even though I was doing the same thing.  I was adding context to the same logger, but didn't provide it output again.  That was the problem.